# Explode based on special characters

Tags: php, regex, yii, explode

I have an issue where, I am not able to explode based on database values.

my database values can be as such

1. 1-10
2. < 10
3. ">20

I want to explode based on specail characters and put them in an array.

for example

```
$array = explode("/ (-) "/, Model::find()->findByPj($model->id));
```

How do I get the regex for that to explode dynamically based on the data

Comment: `explode()` doesn't take a regex pattern.  Try `preg_split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode()` can't handle regular expressions. You are looking for [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and the correct pattern is `(-|<|>)`. The pattern basically means: match `-` or `<` or `>`.
So the code should look like this:

```
$array = preg_split("/ (-|<|>) /", Model::find()->findByPj($model->id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_split(regex_pattern, string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like this:

```
$array = preg_split("(-)", 'some string here, lorem-ipsum'); 
var_dump($array);
```

Hope this helps!